# ReactJSA Typescript Route JSX Element is not accepting

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Good day everyone,
I am new to ReactJS/Typescript and need some tips with below behavior. I want to restrict access to Dashboard component with below codes:

```
const DashBoard = () => {
    return (
        <h1> DashBoard </h1 >
    )
}
export default DashBoard;
```

Protecting  route to DashBoard component by using in other component NavBar:

```
....
<PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={DashBoard} exact isAuth={true} />
...
```

Below is PrivateRoute:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

interface PrivateRouteProps {
    path: string;
    exact: boolean;
    component: JSX.Element; //using component: React.FC works
    isAuth: boolean;
}
const PrivateRoute = (props: PrivateRouteProps) => {

    return props.isAuth ? (<Route path={props.path} exact={props.exact} component={props.component} />) :
        (<Redirect to="/login" />);
};
export default PrivateRoute;
```

However, I got below error:

```
Type '() => Element' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key
```

**My questions:**

**Using  "component: React.FC" or "component: any" will get above error gone  but is this safe as I am returning JSX.Element in all components as per https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react**

Thank you

Comment: Would rather go for `React.ReactNode` or `(name: string) => React.ReactNode`.

Answer (score 0):

Using component: React.FC is indeed the right approach.

This will handle your generic types, the default prop types (like children) and the return types of your components' function(as JSX elements).

Comment: It's my pleasure!